# Unable to work with Session in later version of ASP.NET MVC framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I had used to work with `Session` in ASP.NET MVC 4 before now I'm using `Session` again with a newer version (.NET framework 4.7.2) and it seems I'm not able to make it work. I'm trying to assign a value to the `Session` object and it seems not storing/saving the value. I tried to test something like this.

Assigning the value into the `Session` object:

```
[Route("Home/CheckUserStatus")]
[HttpGet]
public String SaveSession()
{
    Session["OpV"] = "dfhfdh9869@#%$456";
    return Session["OpV"].ToString();
}
```

Retrieving the value from the session:

```
[Route("Test/AddUsers")]
[HttpGet]
public String RetrieveSesssion()
{
    if (Session["OpV"] != null)
    {
        return Session["OpV"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "Session is empty";
    }
}
```

When I execute the `RetrieveSesssion()` method after the `SaveSession()` has been executed, it always returns "Session is empty". I'm not sure which part I still missed here. Kindly advised. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
public String RetrieveSesssion()
{
    string sessionvar = SaveSession();

    if (sessionvar != null)
    {
        return sessionvar;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Session is empty";
    }
}
```

This works fine!

Comment: So we can't pass the value of Session directly anymore? I remember before I can pass it directly anywhere along with the data being stored. Not sure, it's not anymore.